# Kafka consumer in spring cloud stream dont start

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

here is the configuration of my consumer

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kafka
      bindings:
        input: 
          destination: greeting
          content-type: application/json
      kafka:   
        binder:
          brokers: kafka
          zkNodes: zookeeper
```

the code of my app

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
@EnableBinding(CommandSink.class)
public class KafkaTesterApplication {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(KafkaTesterApplication.class);

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaTesterApplication.class, args);
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel="input")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        logger.debug("receive {}", message);
    }
}
```

and the sink interface

```
public interface CommandSink {
    public static final String CHANNEL = "input";

    @Input(CommandSink.CHANNEL)
    SubscribableChannel command();

}
```

it looks like consumer doesn't connect to zookeeper and kafka.
any idea?

Comment: Enable DEBUG logging; it should tell you what's going on.

Comment: thx your response, publishing the solution in the same time.

Comment: What version of Stream are you using? Also, replace the ServiceActivator annotarion by StreamListener, only StreamListener enables competing consumers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we found the solution...

We don't know why but a topic was missing.  The most curious in the problem was that the consumer with zookeeper (old style) can consume messages.

The missing topic was

> __consumer_offsets